# Ambethia Recaptcha Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@video=Video.find(params[:id])
        @video.increment!(:votes)
        respond_to do|format|
        format.js
```

This works fine.I want to add recaptcha validation to it.Iam using Ambethia recaptcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add *gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'* to your Gemfile, run bundle
- Create your reCAPTCHA keys: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
- Add the public and private key to your project and restart your server:

config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = 'xxx'
  config.private_key = 'yyy'
end
```

in your view:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

in your controller:

```
 def create
   if verify_recaptcha

   else

   end
 end
```

Comment: I have the gem installed.I want to know how to validate it in the controller :)

Comment: My copy/paste failed ;)  Now it is complete.

Comment: Its not working.I have the following in the controller `def vote
  if verify_recaptcha
  @video=Video.find(params[:id])
  @video.increment!(:votes)
  respond_to do|format|
  format.js  
     end
    else
       @video=Video.find(params[:id])
       respond_to do|format|
  format.js  (render 'failure.js.erb')
  end
 end
 end` when vote button is clicked, nothing happens.The vote value is not incremented.It works fine if recaptcha is removed.

Comment: I'm using the Ajax Api.it displays the captcha. `$('#cap_<%=@video.id%>').each(function () {
    Recaptcha.create('6LcUkcISAAAAAHkKSVVg3BAYbwGNUukOmUZp8I9j', this);
});`, but vote value is not incremented.

Comment: ah, forgot to restart the server